# Parameter Value Request on Query Refresh

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL that is working and returning the information i need from MS-Access, however it keeps asking for me to enter paramter values for "Annual Accrual" and "Used".

```
    SELECT SchedulingLog.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category AS Type, 
           Sum(SchedulingLog.Value) AS Used, SchedulingLog.Category, 
           qry_YearsOfService.[Annual Vac Days], [Annual Vac Days]+[Used] AS [Days Left]
    FROM   SchedulingLog INNER JOIN qry_YearsOfService ON 
           SchedulingLog.UserID = qry_YearsOfService.UserID
    GROUP BY SchedulingLog.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category, SchedulingLog.Category, 
             qry_YearsOfService.[Annual Vac Days], [Annual Vac Days]+[Used]
    HAVING (((SchedulingLog.Category) Like "Vac*"));
```

I dont want the option to enter parameter, it should just calculate.  What am I missing?

Here is the SQL for the Years of Service query

```
    SELECT Roster.UserID, Roster.[WM DOH], Round((Date()-[WM DOH])/365,2) AS YearsOfService, 
Max (tblAccrual.WeeksAccrual) AS [Annual Accrual], Roster.Schedule, 
[Annual Accrual]*[Schedule] AS [Annual Vac Days]
    FROM Roster, tblAccrual
    WHERE ((([tblAccrual]![Years])<Round((Date()-[WM DOH])/365,2)))
    GROUP BY Roster.UserID, Roster.[WM DOH], 
Round((Date()-[WM DOH])/365,2), Roster.Schedule, [Annual Accrual]*[Schedule];
```

Comment: What happens when you run qry_YearsOfService all by itself does it ask for those parameters?  It looks like you are summarizing data from a query looking for parameters.

Comment: I don't think you need to group by SchedulingLog.Category twice

Comment: Yes it does ask for "Annual Accrual".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's asking for `[Annual Accrual]` because you have `[Annual Accrual]*[Schedule]` in the `group by` clause of your first query.  Try taking that out.

Asking for `[Used]` for the same reason, as you have `[Annual Vac Days]+[Used]` referenced in the `group by` clause of your second query.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have 2 different problems.

There is no field named "Annual Accrual" in that SQL.  Perhaps it is included in `qry_YearsOfService` but spelled incorrectly(?).  Show us the SQL for `qry_YearsOfService` if you can't find the problem.

Your `GROUP BY` clause references `[Used]`, which is an alias defined in the field expression list.  I suspect the db engine interprets it as a parameter in the `GROUP BY` because it is quite restrictive about allowing you to use field aliases later in a query.  I think you need to change that.  Show us brief samples from `SchedulingLog` and `qry_YearsOfService` if you want help sorting that out.

Apart from those issues, your field list includes `SchedulingLog.Category` twice, the first time aliased as `Type` and the second time unaliased.  I don't understand the point of that.  Including the same field twice may not create a problem, however `Type` might because it's a reserved word.  If you keep that as the alias, enclose it in square brackets just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using "Annual Accrual" anywhere in this query, so it must be called from qry_YearsOfService, or an even further nested query.

As for "Used", change your reference to Sum(SchedulingLog.Value) in the Group By.